# Google Authentication process using Auth2 approach not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, google-authentication

Our site allows our user's to authenicate using thier google credentials.  Due to some Google API changes I've had to rewrite the process.  The new approach is working on all browsers except IE.  Any thoughts?  IE is not erroring, but never returns to the listener after the authenication window closes.

```
<telerik:RadScriptBlock runat="server" ID="ctlGoogleScripts">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" "></script>v
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var apiKey = 'our api key';
      var discoveryDocs = ["https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"];
      var clientId = 'our client id';
      var scopes = 'profile';

      function handleClientLoad() {
        // Load the API client and auth2 library
          gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
       }

        function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: apiKey,
            discoveryDocs: discoveryDocs,
            clientId: clientId,
            scope: scopes,
            'immediate': false
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
        });
      }

      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
                    makeApiCall();
        }
      }

      function handleAuthClick() {
        // here is my current issue, need to see if the user is signed in or not
        var isSignedIn = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get();
        if (isSignedIn) {
            makeApiCall();
        }
        else {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
        }
      }

      function makeApiCall() {
        // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
        gapi.client.people.people.get({ 
          'resourceName': 'people/me',
          'requestMask.includeField': 'person.emailAddresses'
        }).then(function(resp) {
          var email = resp.result.emailAddresses[0].value;
          //call server-side method to encrypt email and refresh page
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "our website address",
            data: "{'emailAddress': '" + email + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (retVal) {
                if (retVal.d !== '') {
                    window.location.href = retVal.d;
                }
            }   
          });
        });
      }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" 
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()" 
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
```

Google Login

Comment: What's your IE browser version? Try to use F12 developer tools to check whether it contain some error? Also, you could check the Http Request via the [Network tab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968260(v=vs.85).aspx#NetworkTab). Besides, you could also check the httprequest in different browsers.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I've tried F12 as well as some console.log messages.  Unfortunately no error is being thrown, but the listener method "updateSigninStatus"  is never being activated.  IE Version is 11.472.17134.0.